\ref not working after Ubuntu upgrade
After an upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04, the \ref command yields a blank while \pageref yields the correct page.  This line
 \item[\S\ref{sec:FaradaysLaw} \textit{Faraday's Law}](p.~\pageref{sec:FaradaysLaw}) has a footnote saying that Faraday and Maxwell used this term.\footnote{\ttfamily https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line\_of\_force}
The formatted text is

The error messages are
Missing number, treated as zero. ...\footnotemark[\ref{least-action-taylor}]
I'm using TeXstudio 4.7.2.  I have also reported this as bug #3903 to TexStudio.  These are the packages in the document that does not compile
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig,color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{cleveref}
These are the packages in the document that does compile
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{epsfig,color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{caption}

False alarm.  Another document compiled correctly.  Package cleverref was missing from the problem document.  Why did it work before?

Correction: the problem is back and switching between documents no longer fixes the problem.

Welcome to TeX.SE.  Without a MWE that shows the problem, we can't really help you.  And most people will assume that you're at fault.  TeXStudio is a front end to tex, and shouldn't be the issue.  Does the log file say anything?  What happens when you compile from a command line, not from TeXStudio?

A sample comment and the packages used are shown in the edited post.  Running pdflatex work2024.tex the ouput ends with ..... :[32] [33]
! Missing number, treated as zero.

\xparse function is not expandable
l.1065 ...\footnotemark[\ref{least-action-taylor}]
may be intuitively cleare...

To clean up the above, the ouput ends with ..... :[32] [33]         ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>                     \xparse function is not expandable  l.1065 ...\footnotemark[\ref{least-action-taylor}]                                                    may be intuitively cleare...

Which TeX distribution (not which TeX front end, and not which operating system) do you use? When did you last update it? Which document class do you employ? A separate request: Instead of strewing useful information across comments, please edit your main posting and update the information you give there.

you've not provided any code we can use to reproduce the problem. your snippet shows a \ref and a \pageref, but no \label. but it probably doesn't like \ref in \footnotemark.

Off-topic: (i) Do yourself a favor and stop loading the epsfig and latexsym packages. (ii) I you must load ulem, please do so with the option normalem. (iii) Unless your LaTeX distribution is more than 6 years old, \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is the default and hence needn't be run. (iv) Are you sure you need to load so many packages in order for your document to compile?

I suggest that you go the folder where your tex file is and remove all files created by tex (.aux, .bbl, etc) -- leave only the files that you have written (tex, bib, images, ...). Do keep a backup for safety! Then compile again.

Just a guess: Instead of \footnotemark[\ref{least-action-taylor}] you want \footref{least-action-taylor}. Because the optional argument of \footnotemark has to be a number suitable to set a counter, but a \ref is not such a number.

The output starts with (base) kuiper@nutmeg2:~/Writing/RAbook-1$ pdflatex book.tex This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)  restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (./book.tex LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2024-01-22> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls Document Class: memoir 2024/01/26 v3.8.2 configurable book, report, article doc ument class

Please edit relevant information into your post.  Please create a minimal working example (MWE).  It's also suspicious that your error message has \ref{least-action-taylor} but the scant amount of code you've shown us doesn't have that.

The problem with providing an MWE is that I have  tested eight documents.  All the article`` documents have no error.  Three out of four memoir``` documents lo longer compile.  I made a spreadsheet of packages used in the memoir documents and tested adding and subtracting packages without solving the problem. So I don't know how to construct a MWE.  Removing the packages as recommended by Mico had no deletrious effect.  I will respond to cabohah separately.

The reference is defined in line 1038: \footnote{\label{least-action-taylor}\ttfamily https://www.eftaylor.com/pub/newton\_mechanics.html}   It produces the error in line 1071.  In fact, all \label definitions produce \ref errors but not pageref errors, not just the end defined in the footnote.  Also, this document compiled all year long, until after the upgrade.

Removing all book.* except book.tex still resulted in a failed compilation.  No new supplementary book were created.

So are you trying to do something like: \documentclass{memoir} \begin{document} Some text \footnote{\label{mylabel}https://tex.stackexchange.com/} with a ref: \ref{mylabel} \end{document}?  Does that cause an error for you?  How does your actual code differ?

Removing all work2024.* except work2024.tex still resulted in a failed compilation.  The auxilary files NOT created again are work2024.blg  work2024.out, work2024.bbl, work2024.lof,  work2024.log.  The only \ref failures are now only in footnotemark.    cabohah 'guess' was a good one!  It appears that \ref no longer produces a number.  I'll check the other documents now.

Problem solved!  Use \footref{...} instead of footnotemark[\ref{...}]. Thank you all.

In LaTeX 2022-06-01 release, \ref was extended to accept an optional star, which made it being non-expandable since then. BTW you may check out this meta Q&A for why a minimal working example (MWE) is so commonly requested in the TeX and friends community.

FWIW, \footnotemake[\ref{...}] caused the error message you reported.  But it is unrelated to the section not appearing in \S\ref{sec:FaradaysLaw}.  But until you can create a 10 line example showing how that happened, we won't be able to help you.

I'm afraid that I can't reproduce that.  It happened on the last compilations before all the compilations failed.  Once the footnote reference problem was solved, I never saw it again.

The following pieces together several comments.  You never really provided sufficient code, but it appears you have something like:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{\label{mylabel}A footnote} with a ref: \ref{mylabel}.
As a footnote\footnotemark[\ref{mylabel}].
\end{document}

This worked up through TeXLive 2021.  TeXLive 2022 changed how ref was defined, so that it no longer works.  The solution is to change \footnotemark[\ref{mylabel}] to \footref{mylabel}.
